# When scraping a webpage that uses Javascript (and perhaps other things)

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'd like to be able to go to a webpage like [this search result within a site](http://www.epicurious.com/tools/searchresults?search=banana) and be able to collect the links to the various results.  I'm using Python's urllib.request and bs4 to do the scraping.  However, to the best of my ability to understand what I'm looking at, the links are inside of some kind of embedded Javascript object.

I tried downloading the HTML source code for the page directly to try to look at it and make sense of it, but it downloaded as a whole folder with pictures and various HTML files and I don't know how a single web page can be a file.  But what I did instead was the following:

```
import urllib.request as ul
url = 'http://www.epicurious.com/tools/searchresults?search=banana'
source = ul.urlopen(url)
with open('pagesource.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(source.read())
```

and then looked at the document it produced.  However, in the document it produced I don't see any links to the recipes in the search results.

Can anyone educate me on what's going on in the page, and how I might be able to collect the links in the search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the HTML in your browser Developer Tools and check for the Anchors linking the recipes. You'll find:

```
<a href="/recipes/food/views/easter-bread-395055" class="recipeLnk">Easter Bread</a>
```

Javascript isn't used for these results. Here is some basic Python3 to get links to all recipes using Requests and BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL_EPICURIOUS_SEARCH="http://www.epicurious.com/tools/searchresults?search="
SEARCH_TEXT="banana"

# Run the search and get the HTML result
response = requests.get(URL_EPICURIOUS_SEARCH + SEARCH_TEXT)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print("HTTP Status:" + response.status_code)
    exit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
# Search for all links with class "recipeLink"
recipes = soup.find_all("a", class_="recipeLnk")

# Loop through the set and print all hrefs.
for recipe in recipes:
    if recipe.has_attr('href'):
        print(recipe['href'])
```

Output:

```
$ python3 recipe-search.py
/recipes/food/views/banana-pudding-356830
/recipes/food/views/banana-bread-51200430
/recipes/food/views/banana-bread-51200020
...
```

Comment: Many thanks. I tried using the Developer Tools but couldn't find the links anywhere in it.  The tools seemed to be organized as folders and again I don't get how a page is a folder--I understand how a page is an HTML file that refers to other objects in a folder but this seems a little more complicated than anything I've learned.  In any case the code you wrote works for me so I'll try to make sense of that and maybe playing with it enough will make everything clear to me.

Comment: Well no, playing with it didn't answer my questions (also tried reading the documentation on `requests`).  As far as I can tell, `requests` simply got more information out of the web page than my code did with `urllib`.  Is there a reason `urllib` only seems to download a portion of the page?  Does this have to do with the web page being a folder--perhaps `requests` was able to handle that and extract all the code from the folder while `urllib` only extracted the code from the main frame HTML file?

Comment: `requests` and `urllib` should retrieve the same data from the server. I use `requests` because it is easier/faster. You could implement the same functionality with `urllib`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy command line tool called wget

```
wget http://www.epicurious.com/tools/searchresults?search=banana
```

This will download the page to a file (same as View Page Source). If you cat out that file and pipe it into a grep for say ... 'Banana Pudding'

```
searchresults?search=banana <-- file generated from wget command above

cat searchresults?search=banana | grep 'Banana Pudding'
```

one of the matches is a line

```
<a href="/recipes/food/views/banana-pudding-356830" class="recipeLnk">Banana Pudding</a>
```

Then use that along with your original URL to formulate a link to the recipe :

```
http://www.epicurious.com +
                         /recipes/food/views/banana-pudding-356830

http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/banana-pudding-356830
```

that bottom link gives you your recipe !  Now just automate what we did here manually